# How to replace the directive Tag with a simple DIV tag

Tags: angular

having this component :

```
@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'chart-cmp',
    template: ''
})
export class ChartComponent implements OnChanges {...}
```

and the HTML template

```
<chart-cmp style="min-width:310px; height: 400px; max-width: 800px; margin: 0 auto;"
        [typeId]="typeId" [username]="username" [grain]="grain"
        (onResult)="onResult($event)"></chart-cmp>
```

It generate the HTML (dom)

```
 <chart-cmp style="min-width:310px; height: 400px; max-width: 800px;
 margin: 0 auto;" ng-reflect-type-id="elec" ng-reflect-username="JTAMISIER">
.... content...
</chart-cmp>
```

but i want a `<DIV>` instead of `<chart-cmp>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use attribute selector instead:

```
selector: '[chart-cmp]',
```

**html**

```
<div chart-cmp></div>
```